# Removing characters from a tuple python

Tags: python

I have made a maths quiz in python. All my code is working fine however when I print the questions it is printing them in brackets and with commas and apostrophes.

```
question = number1, '+', number2
```

That is the name of my tuple:

```
answer = int(input("What is {}?".format(question)))
```

That is where I print the question:

```
What is (2, '*', 4)?
```

That is what my output looks like.
I want to know how to remove the ( , '', ).
Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you use a '+' and it outputs a '*' ? And are you sure it prints the brackets?

Comment: str((2, '*', 4)).replace(",", "").replace("'", "")

Comment: Where do I place this?

Answer (score 2):

About your error:

`question = number1, '+', number2` defines a tuple with 3 elements

Example:

```
>>> question = 2, '+', 4
>>> print(question)
(2, '+', 4)
>>> type(question)
tuple
```

With `"What is {}?".format(question)` you build a `str` from one parameter `question`. The `format` method converts the tuple `question` to `str` and insert it in your `string`. That's why your output contains `(`, `'` and `)` like a tuple.

```
>>> str((2, '*', 4))
(2, '*', 4)
```

In your case you can build a `str` question by using that:

```
question = "%i + %i" % (number1, number2)
```

or

```
question = "{} + {}".format(number1, number2)
```

and use it again in the function `input()`:

```
answer = int(input("What is {} ".format(question)))
```

---

Or you can use **tuple** `question` directly so:

```
question = number1, '+', number2
answer = int(input("What is {} {} {}".format(*question)))
```

*`*` converts a tuple/list variable to a list of parameters. So you have 3 parameters here. Because of that you need 3 `{}`*

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be

```
question = '{} {} {}'.format(number1, operator, number2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to format twice

```
answer = int(input("What is {0} + {1}?".format(number1, number2)))
```